# ubuntu-touch: packages not configured in libertine containers

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, libertine

**Situation**

I have installed a number of programs in a libertine container - some via the libertine command, and some by 'apt get' after entering the container.

It seems that many of them are not properly conifgured - or that dependencies are not configured.

**Symptoms**

This is what I see if I try to install something in the container with apt-get:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+7ubuntu4) ...
open: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package x11-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libice6:armhf:
 libice6:armhf depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libice6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsm6:armhf:
 libsm6:armhf depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsm6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxt6:armhf:
 libxt6:armhf depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libxt6:armhf depends on libsm6; however:
  Package libsm6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxt6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up isc-dhcp-client (4.3.1-5ubuntu2.3) ...
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/run/user/32011/confined/com.ubuntu.terminal/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package isc-dhcp-client (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Setting up dictionaries-common (1.23.17) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript-x:
 ghostscript-x depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ghostscript-x (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of transfig:
 transfig depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package transfig (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xournal:
 xournal depends on ghostscript-x; however:
  Package ghostscript-x is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xournal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/run/user/32011/confined/com.ubuntu.terminal/ca-certificates.crt.tmp.XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.23.17) ...
mktemp: failed to create directory via template ‘/run/user/32011/confined/com.ubuntu.terminal/ispell-auto.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
ispell-autobuildhash: Cannot make temporary directory under "/run/user/32011/confined/com.ubuntu.terminal". Aborting ...
update-default-ispell: Error running ispell-autobuildhash
dpkg: error processing package dictionaries-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 25
Errors were encountered while processing:
 x11-common
 libice6:armhf
 libsm6:armhf
 libxt6:armhf
 isc-dhcp-client
 ghostscript-x
 transfig
 xournal
 ca-certificates
 dictionaries-common
```

full output here : https://paste.ubuntu.com/17474260/

I'm not sure if the output is always important. Xournal is flagged as not being installed correctly but it does work.

**Question**

Could anyone shed some light on this? Is it something that can be corrected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recurring problem if you try to set up a Libertine container from the Terminal App, and caused by the confinement of the Terminal App.

Please try again using an `ssh` or `adb shell` session, which is fully unconfined.

A better long-term solution for this problem is under development but unlikely to be delivered before OTA-13.

Comment: So from another machine I should ssh into the tablet to create a libertine container?

Comment: Yes.  Once the container is created the Terminal App should work OK.

Comment: Does this mean `ssh localhost` from within the terminal app should work as well?

Comment: I am accepting this answer, just commenting here to say to future readers that ssh'ing in from another machine works.